# Qodana fail to load the report

Tags: gitlab-ci, qodana

When I run Qodana in Gradle using its plugin. everything works fine but while displaying the report I see the below exception. I can see report.html being generated in `build/results/reports` folder and a similar issue is being replicated in my gitlab-ci.

using qodana `qodana-jvm-community:2023.3` version

```
Showing Qodana report from http://localhost:8080/...
time="2024-01-18T14:18:37Z" level=fatal msg="Qodana report not found. Get a report by running `qodana scan`"
```

```
qodanaScan {
    arguments = [
            "--save-report",
            "--show-report"
    ]
}
```

```
qodana {
    cachePath = "localpath"
}
```